# Fill select menu from get request

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using spring boot and I wanted to fill a select option menu from my database table for which I've done the following

In my controller class I've

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView area() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("area");
        model.addObject("list", areaService.listAllArea());


        model.addObject("teamKey", hubService.listAllHubs());//It works perfectly and do return values

        return model;
    }
```

here I've returned two objects of "list" and "teamKey" for list i've populated table and for teamKey I want to populate a dropdown for user selection. here is my jsp

```
  <select class="form-control" th:field="${operator.hubID}"  id="dropOperator">
            <option value="0" th:text="select operator" ></option>
            <option th:each="operator : ${teamKey}" th:value="${operator.hubID}" th:text="${operator.name}"></option>
        </select>
```

I've copied this example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715276/how-do-i-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-list-using-thymeleaf-and-spring) but It only shows empty dropdown and I do have value inside my database table and I've checked it by filling table grid with "teamKey".

here is my hub class

```
@Entity                         
@Table(name="Hub")
public class Hub {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long hubID;
    public long getHubID() {
        return hubID;
    }
    public void setHubID(long hubID) {
        this.hubID = hubID;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.name = Name;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private String description;

}
```

Comment: my model class do have hubID and name in it

Answer (score 0):

I had to loop through items of hubs something like this

```
 <select name="hubs" >
                <c:forEach  items="${teamKey}" var="lou">
                    <option value="${lou.hubID}">${lou.name}</option>   
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

hope this help other for spring boot