# I study thymeleaf but i don't know what does it mean this th:field from this <select>

Tags: java, spring, web, thymeleaf

I try to do a dropdown list with some files and I find this example and I don't know what it should contain the th:field. Please can you tell me also what it should contain the post method in spring if I what to have the selected value? Please help me!! :)

```
<select th:field="*{type}">
<option th:each="type : ${allTypes}" 
      th:value="${type}" 
      th:text="#{${'seedstarter.type.' + type}}">Wireframe</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) as well as [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc) it's the name of the property in the form-backing bean, so the name of the field from your object, where you want to store the value (the examples use inputs but the idea is the same for all components).

Comment: @Morfic,  but in this example : 

       <div class="form-group blu-margin">
       <select class="form-control" th:field="${operator.opeId}"  id="dropOperator">
    <option value="0" th:text="select operator" ></option>
       <option th:each="operator : ${operators}" 
         th:value="${operator.id}" th:text="${operator.operatorName}">
       </option>
       </select>
    </div>

The entity Operator doesn't have a field .openId... I don't understand..

Comment: If you're referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715276/how-do-i-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-list-using-thymeleaf-and-spring), indeed, the entity does not have `opeId`, it has `id` which is used as the value for the items in the dropdown. However, the user probably (they don't say explicitly) is binding the data to some other object. Perhaps it's a form where the user can input something related to an operator, for example scheduling shifts or making an inventory. You type your data, and then select the person to which the data belongs. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thank you! :)

Comment: Cu placere! If this answers your question(or solves your problem) you can chose @LAT94 's answer below, which says basically the same but was posted before me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Tutorial: Thymeleaf + Spring](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html) (go to 7.2 Inputs) it says that it is a model binding with your form and beans.

Comment: In this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715276/how-do-i-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-list-using-thymeleaf-and-spring  th:filed seems to have other role from valide answer.

Comment: How come? The th:field="${operator.opeId}" is how you can get the operatorName at option tag (th:text="${operator.operatorName}")
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715276/how-do-i-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-list-using-thymeleaf-and-spring>