# Invoke method when Dropdown value selected in SpringBoot Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dropdown

I can able to invoke the method when submit the button.But I need to invoke method when drop down value selected from drop down list in SpringBoot.

I tried using below but didn't worked.

Please find the sample code as shown below:

```
<select th:field="*{country}" xmlns:th="th">
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="first">1</option>
   <option value="second">2</option>
   <option value="third">3</option>
</select>
```

Java code:

```
@Controller
public class Countries() {

  @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String menu(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("createMenu", new Country());

        return "menu";
    }

  @RequestMapping("/first")
    public List<Object> country(){

        System.out.println("first");

        return null;

    }
 }
```

When selected dropdown value then invoke method to get list of states.Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: please can you check this question and answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715276/how-do-i-populate-a-drop-down-with-a-list-using-thymeleaf-and-spring

Comment: You need to use `javascript/jquery` to catch change event.

Comment: so is not possible in java class? thanks @want2learn