# Dropdown list using Thymeleaf in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to load drop down list using ArrayList in Springboot as i am new to springboot.

I have tried but not working as expected.

Please find  the code which i have tried as below:

## Java Code:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

@GetMapping("/create")
     public String create(Model model) {

      model.addAttribute("create", new Demo());

      return "create";

     }

     public void countriesList(Model model) {

          List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();

          countryList.add("US");
          countryList.add("UK");

          model.addAttribute("countries", countryList);

       }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/create}" th:object="${create}" method="post">

        <select th:field="*{country}">
             <option value=""> -- </option>
             <option th:each="country : ${countries}" th:value="${country}" th:text="${country}"></option>
        </select>
</form>
```

Finally no errors but only loading in dropdown list with `--` and not loading the countries.

Please help me on this.

Comment: please add the error you are getting

Comment: *I have tried but not working as expected and getting errors.* And why do you think that not including those errors in your question is good idea?

Comment: Besides, you are not adding anything to the model.

Comment: How to add model..Please help me as i am new to Springboot.Thanks @Antoniossss

Comment: the `countryList` have to be added to the model so it can be accessed by thymeleaf. `model.addAttribute("countries", countryList);`

Comment: I have added as suggested but still getting error. I have updated my post with new code.. please check and help me. thanks @Valentin Carnu

Comment: @Chassu for `th:field` try replacing `${countries}` with `*{countries}` (details on [thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs))

Comment: @Chassu maybe the accepted answer from [How do I populate a drop down with a list using thymeleaf and spring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37723208/10386912) thread helps

Comment: I have already seen that but no full controller class code and as i trying with arraylist. now no errors but countries are not loading in drop down. Updated new code in post.. please check. Thanks @Valentin Carnu

Comment: @Chassu you arent calling the `countriesList()` method in `create()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never called your function for adding countries to the model...

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

 @GetMapping("/create")
 public String create(Model model) {

  model.addAttribute("create", new Demo());
  countriesList(model); // this line is needed
  return "create";

 }

 private void countriesList(Model model) {

  List < String > countryList = new ArrayList < > ();

  countryList.add("US");
  countryList.add("UK");

  model.addAttribute("countries", countryList);

 }
}
```

Comment: After adding this line - `countriesList(model);` working without any issues. thank you @Nodir Rashidov

Comment: Please help me that how to invoke a method when selected value in dropdown list? thanks @Nodir Rashidov

Answer (score 0):

try with this code block

```
 <span th:each="country:${countries}" th:remove="tag">
          <option th:value="${country}" th:text="${country}"></option>
    </span>
```

Comment: No errors , but nothing on page as dropdown list is not showing on page. Please help me.Thanks @pantha istiaque